# Wordpresss how to fix this issue: Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break"

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with my website, im not a developer so I am not an expert in this field, and built the website without any code:

Issue in the website:

[image]

The following message which shows up:

> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01ak/b1529/ipg.zubair89229/advicecube/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2851

> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01ak/b1529/ipg.zubair89229/advicecube/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2855

> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /hermes/bosnacweb01/bosnacweb01ak/b1529/ipg.zubair89229/advicecube/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php on line 3708

Anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are not using the correct version of PHP for this software. Even minor changes in the version number of PHP can change the way way it works.

It is probably best to ask the author of the software about this.

Comment: Hey, firstly, thanks a lot for replying, its a wordpress website which I am the admin of, and monitor occasionally, and I am not a developer and just built it without any kind of coding. So I wanna know how can I check or fix the issue, as you had said that the php may be incorrect, where should I go on my wordpress dashboard to fix it? Thanks and kind regards

Comment: @AnasZubair To check your PHP version you need to get a command prompt and type php -version . It is actually rather difficult to get exactly the PHP version you want because not all possible versions are still available for download for particular Linux distributions. In any case installation can be difficult depending on the particular version because you may have to download source code and compile it. (Yuk) I suggest you try to talk to someone at Wordpress to see if your version is the problem.